# Identifying directory to download from in FTP for different dates

Tags: c#, ftp, tree, download, directory

We need to create or integrate some existing software which identifies the FTP folder to download files. 
The problem here is the folder structure will be configured by the user according to how the client stores them on FTP at run time and stored in some xml or DB.

The folder structure needs to be generic so that we can easily configure it for any type of structure. The folder or file names can contain dates or part of date in their names which change everyday according to the date.

For eg. we can have a folder Files_DDMMYYYY and inside that there will be specific files which have to be downloaded everyday. 
OR
A single folder in which different files can contain dates.

Comment: first of all, it's not clear at all what your question is. Please clarify. Secondly, stating "i'm lazy and I'm expect code" won't get you new friends here...

Comment: Need more information then this

Comment: So, you're looking for someone to code a complete solution?

Answer (score 2):

The first major improvement you can make to your solution is a very simple one.

That would be to restructure the date format in your folder structure from using

**Files_DDMMYYYY**

to using

**Files_YYYYMMDD**

This way, your folders will list in the directory in sequential order.  Otherwise, your files will be crosscut sorted by the day of the month and then the month of the year and then the year.  With DDMMYYYY you'll see them listed something like this:

- 01102011
- 01102012
- 01102013
- 01112011
- 01112012
- 01112013
- 01122011
- 01122012
- 01122013
- 15102011
- 15102012
- 15102013
- 15112011
- 15112012
- 15112013
- 15122011
- 15122012
- 15122013

With them YYYYMMDD you'll see them

- 20111001
- 20111015
- 20111101
- 20111115
- 20111201
- 20111215
- 20121001
- 20121015
- 20121101
- 20121115
- 20121201
- 20121215
- 20131001
- 20131015
- 20131101
- 20131115
- 20131201
- 20131215

As I said, it's a very simple change that will help keep your structure organized.  The second list is automatically sequentially ordered by date.